# Comparing apns tokens as strings?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm starting out with apns, we have a method in the app delegate where we receive the apns token. I want to send it up to my server, but only if it is different than the last received token (I think this is the right way to do it?).

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSString* newToken = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString* oldToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"lastToken"];

    if ([newToken isEqualToString:oldToken]) {
        // Nothing to do, token hasn't changed.
    }
    else {
        // 1) Send token up to my server.
        // 2) On successful send, overwrite local copy of token.
    }
}
```

The library I'm using on my server to send the apns messages eventually wants the token as a string (I'm using [javapns](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/)). So I need to convert it at some point. I also want to store it locally as a string. Is there a better way to do this?

Lastly, will both of these strings be autoreleased?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For APNS tokens you should store them in hex, so:

```
NSMutableString* binaryString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:deviceToken.length];
unsigned char* bytes = (unsigned char*) [deviceToken bytes];
for (int i = 0 ; i < deviceToken.length ; i++)
    [binaryString appendFormat:@"%02x", bytes[i]];
```

If you're using ARC, then they will be autoreleased.

Answer (score 1):

I took a similar approach as you do and I'm quite happy with it:

```
NSString *tt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",devToken];
NSString *deviceToken = [[tt substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [tt length]-2)]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];       

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (![[defaults valueForKey:@"deviceToken"] isEqualToString:deviceToken]) {
    [defaults setValue:deviceToken forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```